# can git checkout be undone?

Tags: git

I had committed my changes on the local and then did accidentally did a checkout from remote branch and have lost all my changes!
Help - is there anyway I can get back to my committed changes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git reflog`

Look for your commit and do a `checkout`.

Comment: @Nacha - Can you tell what you did to solve? As in, the command.

Comment: @manojlds: `git reflog` shows all the recent commit changes, including switching to different branches. One only needs to identify the required commit and just do `git checkout`. If the consequence is a detached state, then one may choose to cherry-pick the required commits, without having to retype all the work.

Comment: @Sailesh - I was expecting answer from OP. I know what git reflog does.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have committed your changes, you need not worry. Just do this:

```
git checkout -
```

it will take you back to the branch you were in.

Answer (score 0):

> Fixing un-committed mistakes
>
> If you've messed up the working tree, but haven't yet committed your
>   mistake, you can return the entire working tree to the last committed
>   state with
>
> $ git reset --hard HEAD

[Git Book](http://book.git-scm.com/4_undoing_in_git_-_reset,_checkout_and_revert.html)